# Read binary file as text

Tags: c#, text, binary

I am unable to parse binary file. I want to read a binary file as plain text and modify its content and then regenerate the updated binary file as a new binary file. I have tried out `BinaryReader` in this regard but it was of no help. Sample data of binary file is given below:

> uêê8uê¸Ÿååàå°Ÿåà áÿ/á Ÿå‘åà‘åœ Ÿåÿ/á0Ÿåïÿ/á@ („Ó%(Ø (
>   À áØ-é°LâÐMâå3[ë0 ã á¨è
>   À áØ-é°LâÐMâ0 ã0å0Kâ  ã° Ãá0ƒâ  ã° Ãá0ƒâ  ã° Ãá0ƒâ  ã° Ãá0ƒâ  ã° Ãá[ëÌ6Ÿå,  ã á ã)8ë
>    ã ë0 á0å0åSã
>   ëœ6Ÿåœ&ŸåÀ ã á á  áò7ëˆ6Ÿåˆ&ŸåÀ ã á á  áë7ët6Ÿåt&Ÿå!À ã á á  áä7ë`&ŸåY0 ãã2ÂåT&ŸåY0 ãä2ÂåH&Ÿå30 ãx1Âå<6Ÿåx1Óå0Kå0Kâ áš7ë  á$6Ÿå ƒå 6Ÿå &ŸåÀ ã á á  áË7ë6Ÿå&ŸåÀ ã á á  áÄ7ëø5Ÿåø%ŸåÀ ã á á  á½7ëÄ%ŸåN0 ãâ2Âå¸5Ÿåâ2ÓåYSãÈ%Ÿå0 ã0‚å¼5Ÿå0“å ƒâ´5Ÿå ƒå°5Ÿå°%ŸåÀ ã á á  á§7ëœ5Ÿåœ%Ÿå  À ã á á  á 7ëP%Ÿå10 ã½1ÂåD%Ÿå10 ãÇ1Âåp5Ÿåp%ŸåÀ ã á á  á“7ë\%Ÿå0 ã0ÂåTŸåTŸåÆ8ëPŸåPŸåÃ8ëL5ŸåL%Ÿå(À ã á á  áƒ7ë85Ÿå8%Ÿå%À ã á á  á|7ë$5Ÿå$%ŸåÀ ã á á  áu7ë5Ÿå%Ÿå)À ã á á  án7ëü4Ÿåü$ŸåÀ ã á á  ág7ëè4Ÿå¼$Ÿå á á›8ëØ4Ÿå°$Ÿå á á–8ëÈ4Ÿå¤$Ÿå á á‘8ë¸4Ÿå˜$Ÿå á áŒ8ë¨4ŸåŒ$Ÿå á á‡8ë0àã0åêü3ŸåÞ2ÓåYSã
>   á8ë0 á0å0åSã    Ô#ŸåY0 ãÞ2Âå ãÝë0 á0åê0 ã0å0åSãèÿÿº04Ÿå0“å  á(4Ÿå ‚à$4ŸåÀ ã á á  á)7ëÒ3ë0 á0å ãÅë0 á0å0åSã
>   ]ë ã|]ë ã ãK]ëÐŸå7së ãu]ë ã ãD]ë¸Ÿå0sëY*ë`

Comment: a) What programming language? b) Show what you've tried.

Comment: Why would you want to read *binary* as *text*? There are bytes (or combinations) that are invalid chars. Those would corrupt your data (you miss a part of the file on reading and/or writing)

Comment: @Hans, well, technically you can use any 8-bit fixed-width encoding that defines all possible bytes, like CP1252. That still doesn't make it a good idea, of course.

Comment: I need to update the contents of the file for that reason I have to read the contents as plain text, or if you have anything else that would help me update the contents of the binary file i am all ears.

Comment: Read it as bytes, change the bytes, write the bytes?

Comment: @Ralf how can i pick up the exact data position where I need to make a change? I am using c# language, moreover how can I read content as plain and record the contents for reference purpose before changing

Comment: @zeeshan How should we know? All we know is that you say its binary. So naturally is reading it as bytes. For example with File.ReadAllBytes. Then changing the bytes in the Array and writing back the file with File.WriteAllBytes.

Comment: @Ralf I have posted sample of my exact data file as binary, but I am unable to convert to readable form for modifying or am I thinking it in the wrong direction?

Comment: @zeeshan No you have posted your data already encoded in a certain encoding. Bytes are bytes are bytes. If you can show them as characters they have been interpreted in some way.

Comment: @Ralf The posted data is in binary form, as in basis.